# In R how can I filter (dplyr) rows and get also the contextual lines?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame with timestamped (sorted) observations.

Is there a way to filter on the value of a variable, and get also the surrounding (contextual) observations even though they do not fulfill the variable condition?

Edit:

I am currently using subset with the conditions + adding the lead and lag, but I am not sure if that is the most efficient way to do it:

```
df <- subset(df, var1==1 | var1==2 | lag(var1)==1 | lead(var1)==1 ...)
```

The code works but I am interested in knowing if it's the most efficient.

Comment: yes, 
please share example data and code that fails..

Answer (score 1):

Another way to subset would be using `dplyr::filter`.

```
df %>% filter(var1 == 1 | var1 == 2 | lag(var1) == 1 | lead(var1) == 1)
```

Right now, you probably have the most efficient way to do it for **small datasets**. We can see this from the following benchmarks.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data_frame(var1 = sample(c(1,2), 2000, replace = T))

library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(your_attempt = {subset(df, var1==1 | var1==2 | lag(var1)==1 | lead(var1)==1)}, 
               new_attempt = {
                 df %>% filter(var1 == 1 | var1 == 2 | lag(var1) == 1 | lead(var1) == 1)}, 
               base_r = {df[df$var1 == 1|df$var1 == 2|lag(df$var1) == 1| lead(df$var1) == 1,]}
               )

# Unit: microseconds
# expr      min        lq      mean   median        uq      max neval
# your_attempt  266.229  281.7310  305.9987  292.255  322.2625  517.952   100
#  new_attempt 1492.703 1582.2990 1666.6932 1616.716 1684.2690 3540.049   100
#       base_r  396.215  419.8235  446.8327  435.183  470.1675  646.232   100

identical(your_attempt, new_attempt)
# [1] TRUE
identical(your_attempt, base_r)
# [1] TRUE
```

however, if you increase the number of rows (to 200000, i.e. `df <- data_frame(var1 = sample(c(1,2), 200000, replace = T))`), the `new_attempt` outmatches the other options:

```
# Unit: milliseconds
#         expr      min        lq      mean    median       uq      max neval
# your_attempt 7.946764 10.631808 15.830630 10.985358 11.73526 97.73276   100
#  new_attempt 6.472834  7.447442  9.530072  9.142661  9.66815 88.33425   100
#       base_r 7.227434  9.903517 14.141587 10.424741 10.84783 89.66881   100
```